# Why does the Visual Studio 2022 'prop' snippet insert 4 spaces instead of 2 for indentation?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Visual Studio 2022, Community Ed.: When using the "prop" and tab shortcut to insert property snippet, the indentation is incorrect

Then indentation for the "prop" snippet should be 2 spaces instead it inserts 4 spaces

The text editors settings (global and C#):

- set to insert spaces (2)
- tried both smart and block indentation
- tried with "adaptive formatting" on and off

other snippets insert with correct indentation.

tried on two different machines with new installation of VS 2022
[property snippet indentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzNfl.gif)

Comment: Can you check whether the snippet has extra spaces inserted? The file should be in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC#\Snippets\1033\Visual C#\prop.snippet` (the path can also be found via Tools => Snippet Manager). Any extensions installed? I can't reproduce it on my end, both `prop` and `propfull` behave identically.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! no extensions installed, I did check the snippet file and it all looked good, this did lead me to search "snippet" under "Tools > options" and came across two enabled experimental settings upon disabling "Show new snippet experience" the problem was resolved :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image: Snippet Options]

By disabling *Show new snippet experience* the issue is resolved and the snippet inserts using the correct indentation.