# Visual Studio 17.8.0 Tab Auto Complete Issue -- Triple Indent

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In Visual Studio I often type **prop** and then hit tab and it turns into a property. Or similarly you can type **cw** tab and it turns into Console.Writeline();.

I recently upgraded my Visual Studio to version 17.8.0, I think I was at 17.6.2 before. In this new version, when I type **prop tab** or **cw tab** Visual Studio triple indents the line. See my figures below:

[image]
[image]

As you can see, **MyProperty** gets triple indented when I hit tab. I tried looking how to fix this and people said to adjust my tab settings, but as far as I can tell they look fine?

[image]

Does anyone know how I can resolve this?

Comment: Can you try resetting your settings from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/environment-settings?view=vs-2022   Also check the Indenting settings under C# as those will override All Languages

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76288116/why-does-the-visual-studio-2022-prop-snippet-insert-4-spaces-instead-of-2-for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I was able to figure out my issue. For some reason if I uncheck this box it fixes my problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I updated Visual Studio to 17.8.0 and tried to enter "prop" and there was no indentation difference.

There may be a problem with your format settings. Try not to perform code format settings in "All Languages". It will affect all languages and may conflict with the format settings of individual languages. You can check first:

Tools=>Options=>Text Editor=>C#=>Tabs=>Check whether the Indent size is the value you expected

If this still doesn't work try opening the Visual Studio Installer to repair Visual Studio

If the issue still exists, please tell me if you try to use ctrl+k, ctrl+d, can you restore the code that has been indented too much?

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to post an answer! I figured out my issued and posted it :)